# Can this cable be used to use my Macbook pro as a screen only?

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors, macbook, hdmi

Can this cable here:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Thunderbolt-Mini-Displayport-To-HDMI-Cable-Adapter-For-Macbook-Pro-Air-iMac-6FT-/271548506237?pt=UK_Computing_Other_Computing_Networking&hash=item3f398d607d

Be used to connect the HDMI side to my PC and the other side to a thunderbolt port on my Macbook Pro Retina 2013 and make it so the PC sends the Image to the mac and displays it on the screen? (Basically use the Amazing retina display as a screen only..)

Comment: No, both ports are for output only.  There's nothing in the cable's description that even suggests that what you want is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot. The hardware does not support using the ports as input. However, internally the MacBook Pro uses DisplayPort. If you wanted to disassemble the machine you could rewire the display to act as an external monitor. Tutorial here: http://mikesmods.com/mm-wp/?p=384